# Updating nested hash parameters. Update action, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, for-loop, nested-forms

I have a nested form that includes a lesson/questions/answers. The user populates answer fields and clicks submit. The hash is shown below:

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Submit Answers", "action"=>"update", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"y##########o=", "lesson"=>{"questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1", "answer"=>{"response"=>"answertextanswertext", "user_id"=>"2"}}, "1"=>{"id"=>"4", "answer"=>{"response"=>"answertextanswertext", "user_id"=>"2"}}}}, "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"lessons"}
```

In my update statement, I would like to loop through the answers and overwrite user_id for security purposes. I modified my update statement to the following:

```
  def update
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    lesson_params = params[:lesson]
    for q in lesson_params[:questions_attributes].values
      for s in q.values
        if !s[:user_id].nil?  
          s[:user_id] = current_user.id.to_s
        end
      end
    end
    if @lesson.update_attributes(lesson_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Answers submitted successfully."
      redirect_to lessons_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

I am a noob, so traversing the nested hash was a bit of trial and error. Is this the appropriate way to loop through the nested hash? Is this a good way to protect against mass-assignment?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0):

When you have nested data structures, looping over them is pretty much the only way to loop over them.  Whether or not it is appropriate is another question.  Realistically, this seems like a lot of work (even though it's pretty straightforward work) just to clean up your user ids.  Honestly, it seems a lot easier to just modify the view that is passing these parameters in to set all those user ids to the currently-logged-in user *before* they get sent to your controller than looping over them (assuming that that is an appropriate solution to whatever security issue you are trying to solve).

Also, you may actually have some scoping issues with (for instance) q.values - this is an array that is equivalent to the values in the hash.  Modifying s[:user_id] may not modify params[:lesson][:question_attributes][0][:user_id] (or whatever it works out to be).

As far as "protecting against mass-assignment" I am not sure why you are worried about that here, can you elaborate?